# JavaScript cashing

Tags: asp.net, javascript

При изменении JavaScript (в отдельном файле) и при перезагрузке страницы, загружается старый скрипт из кэша броузера. Перезагрузка страницы с помощью Ctrl-F5 загружает новый скрипт.
Есть ли какая-нибудь комманда, которая на серверной стороне даст команду броузеру загружать JavaScript не из кэша?

Например, чтобы броузер не кэшировал страницу я использую

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) 
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    ...
}
```

Нужно тоже самое, но про скрипты в отдельных файлах!

UPD: Для критиков: Убрать кэширование нужно только для удобства тестирования, после запуска приложения эти строки уберу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел интересный подход в сети:

Цитата:

> You may pass a version string as a get
>   parameter to the URL of your script
>   tag. The parameter won't be evaluated
>   by the static JavaScript file but
>   force the browser to get the new
>   version.
>
> If you do not want to assign the
>   version string every time you edited
>   the source you may compute it based on
>   the file system time stamp or your
>   subversion commit number:
>
> ```
> <script src="/script.js?time_stamp=1224147832156" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script src="/script.js?svn_version=678" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

Источник:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206783/when-does-browser-automatically-clear-javascript-cache

UPD:
для полноты информации

```
    <script src="/script.js?timestamp=<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") %>"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Это достаточно популярный подход =)

Comment: я не знал ))

Answer (score 2):

Я точно так и делаю. Дописываю таймстемп к ссылке на скрипт.

```
//функция загружает яваскрипт
    function get_js(sname) {
        var loadedJS = document.createElement('script'); //создаем DOM-элемент и задаем его параметры
        loadedJS.src = sname;
        loadedJS.type = "text/javascript";
        loadedJS.language = "javascript";

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; //получаем элемент секции head

        head.appendChild(loadedJS); //вставляем новый script в head
    }

    function get_timestamp() { //возвращает таймстемп
        var obj_date = new Date();
        var timestamp = obj_date.getTime();
        return timestamp;
    }
    //вызов функции подгрузки
get_js("modules/translation/mech_vars.js?randomData="+get_timestamp());
```

Answer (score 1):

Это потому, что скрипты не обрабатываются ASP.NET. Вы должны верно сконфигурировать IIS-сервер. Либо используйте переименование файловдобавление запроса к имени js-файла в качестве обходного пути.